# 502: Nodejs app via Nginx proxy Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: node.js, nginx, vps

### Setup

Running an Ubuntu 18.04 on a Virtual Private Server. Installed Nginx (to work as a proxy), serving Nodejs app using PM2.

### Problem

Worked for a month now suddenly the server returns a 502:

> 2018/10/10 00:39:51 [error] 1009#1009: *19 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 176.104.---.---, server: foo.bar.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4000/", host: "foo.bar.com"
>
> 2018/10/10 00:39:51 [error] 1009#1009: *19 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 176.104.---.---, server: foo.bar.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://localhost/favicon.ico", host: "foo.bar.com", referrer: "https://foo.bar.com/"
>
> 2018/10/10 01:10:15 [error] 1009#1009: *24 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 176.104.--.---, server: foo.bar.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://[::1]:4000/", host: "foo.bar.com"
>
> 2018/10/10 01:10:15 [error] 1009#1009: *24 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 176.104.---.---, server: foo.bar.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4000/", host: "foo.bar.com"
>
> 2018/10/10 01:10:15 [error] 1009#1009: *24 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 176.104.---.---, server: foo.bar.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://localhost/favicon.ico", host: "foo.bar.com", referrer: "https://foo.bar.com/"

### Configs:

- [nginx.conf](https://gist.github.com/h3d0/46038b62b0779c6baada098ea9a03326)
- [Per-site blocks](https://gist.github.com/h3d0/c902566e93b73075fe9a4b113dbfccc6)

### Important

The most important - this config worked perfectly for month. Then it stopped working. This happened when the new version of the app was uploaded. Have rolled back to the previous version (full copy of the whole system). But now even previous version (which worked) doesn't work with the same error. So scratching the head here.

### Firewall

```
sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
**/tcp                     ALLOW       ******
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

### Update

I have tried to serve just a static HTML file and it worked. I have tried to serve a dummy hello-world Expressjs app and it worked. So the problem seems to be with the Angular's generated *server.js* (Universal engine).

Comment: Could you provide your NGINX config file please?

Comment: Added to the description.

Comment: Do you have whitelisted in the firewall HTTP traffic?

Comment: Yes. See *Firewall* section added to the description. I am reading that Nginx + Nodejs are some times related to the wrong port exposed. In my case the Node app is running at localhost:4000 and Nginx listens for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 502 Bad gateway error means your backend is not reachable by NGINX. 
Make sure pm2 runs the NodeJS app and listens on 4000/TCP. 
You can simply check it by `curl` or `netstat` with these commands:

```
netstat -ntlp | grep :4000
curl http://127.0.0.1:4000
```

Comment: Tried to run my *server.js* (which Node server) 1) using `pm2` and 2) calling it with `node server.js`. In both cases `netstat` would return nothing, `curl` showed `connection refused`. So it seems to be my Nodejs doesn't run properly? This is Angular 2 project, *server.js* was generated by Angular Univarsal engine.

Comment: I have tried to put a dummy *index.html* file and serve it via Nginx - it works. So it looks Node is the reason. Investigating this further.

Comment: @Oleg Yes, The problem is pm2 or NodeJS app. try to check pm2 logs with `pm2 logs`